# Devexpress Pivot Grid Control ordering (winforms)

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

We are using a very old version of devexpress (version 11.something). I am trying to use the "ordering" functionality on a pivot grid.

[image]

1. What is the area called in the red circle.
2. How can I specify the number of columns allowed in this area.
3. When more than n number of columns, the functionality disappears, how can I avoid this

[image]